# Hyper-V with Ubuntu 20.04 Guest No Virtualization

Tags: virtualization, desktop-environments, qemu, hyper-v, virt-manager

On windows server 2012 install Hyper-V with VT-x in de bios enabled.
The guest is Ubuntu 20.04

lscpu give:

```
Architecture:                    x86_64  
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit  
Byte Order:                      Little Endian  
Address sizes:                   42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual  
CPU(s):                          2  
On-line CPU(s) list:             0,1  
Thread(s) per core:              1  
Core(s) per socket:              2  
Socket(s):                       1  
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel  
CPU family:                      6  
Model:                           79  
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6800K CPU @ 3.40GHz  
Stepping:                        1  
CPU MHz:                         3399.997  
BogoMIPS:                        6799.99  
Hypervisor vendor:               Microsoft  
Virtualization type:             full  
L1d cache:                       64 KiB  
L1i cache:                       64 KiB  
L2 cache:                        512 KiB  
L3 cache:                        30 MiB  
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0,1  
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Vulnerable  
Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion  
Vulnerability Mds:               Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode; SMT Host state unknown  
Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI  
Vulnerability Mmio stale data:   Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode; SMT Host state unknown  
Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Vulnerable  
Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization  
Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Retpolines, STIBP disabled, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS Not affected  
Vulnerability Srbds:             Not affected  
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode; SMT Host state unknown  
Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxs  
                                 r sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl cpuid pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma
                                  cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnow
                                 prefetch pti fsgsbase bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms rtm xsaveopt
```

After downloaded /compiled and installed QEMU version 7.1, I get the message in Desktop Virt-manager 2.2.1, Error host does not support virtualization options.

What can I do to let VT-x nested to work?

Comment: Error message seems pretty clear. windows server 2012  Error host does not support virtualization options

Comment: You need to go into your windows host server and in its BIOS settings enable virtualization.  if that server is itself a virtual server then you need to enable exposing the virtualization flags to the guest Windows VM via the host machine before you can then nest another VM inside it.  This is a hardware / host system configuration though to expose the virtualization extensions, and not an Ubuntu issue necessarily

Comment: I think it is much easy to search in google first :) [How to Enable Nested Virtualization in Hyper-V](https://petri.com/how-to-enable-nested-virtualization-in-hyper-v/).

Comment: Yes david, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

As I found out after long searching is the minimum Hyper_V server to support nested virtualization is Windows Server 2016
The other choice is Ubuntu 20.04-22.04 with KVM / QEMU who support nested virtualization
The man demand for both is a motherboard that support Intel VT-x vmx